# В реляционной базе данных как организовать хранение таблицы пользователей - по ID или ID + Имя пользователя?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, auth, asp-net-core-mvc

У меня есть таблица users, где имя является первичным ключом. Он используется для проверок, уникальности, входа и так далее. Но есть проблема – имя пользователя изменить нельзя. Нужен идентификатор в этом случае? Как в таком случае, имея идентификатор, проверять уникальность записей, вход по имени пользователя и так далее? Реляционная база данных, в будущем будут добавляться связанные таблицы (наборы прав пользователей)

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В реляционной алгебре есть такое понятие как альтернативный ключ. Более чем один столбец может быть уникальным.

Для обозначения альтернативных ключей в SQL существует ограничение уникальности (`UNIQUE`).

Чаще всего строковое поле (такое имя пользователя) делают уникальным, а ссылки на таблицу по суррогатному ключу (ID)

Comment: Спасибо, я примерно так себе и представлял схему. Почитаю.